# Convert data from string to datetime in a dataset

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert data from a dataset from string to DateTime. However I have tried DateTime.Parse and ToDateTime, however both of these still give me the date in a string format. Is there a way of converting the property the data in a dataset.

Dataset call

```
DataSet dtAllLocations = api.GetLatestUsageAccessLevel(utility,AreaLevel,AreaLevelID,pageTheme,State.DayPlusN);
foreach (DataRow dr in dtAllLocations.Tables["yearPreviousUsage"].Rows)
  {
     dr["Datestamp"] = DateTime.Parse(dr["Datestamp"].ToString());
  }
```

Comment: Code please....

Comment: You have to watch this date somewhere(f.e. the debugger's quick watch window), there it is displayed as string with a specific format. But `DateTime.Parse` returns really a `DateTime`. You need to provide your code.

Comment: Could you please check your code ??

Comment: I am up voting just to counter the down votes.

Comment: I'm sorry, where exactly are you using `DateTime.Parse`?

Comment: @gurps We want you to show us how you made the data set into a string that you want to convert to a datetime. This way we can see what problems you have.

Comment: I am getting this from an API, which I don't have access to

Comment: @KyloRen Countering downvotes with upvotes will not help the OP with asking better questions. Refrain from doing so we will have better questions.

Comment: @KyloRen _"I am up voting just to counter the down votes_ - If you want to upvote a question that **didn't** have any code at the time, you're not doing yourself; readers or the OP any favors.  [ask] --

Comment: Instead of `DateTime.Parse(dr["Datestamp"].ToString())` try `dr.Field<DateTime>("Datestamp")`. No need to convert it to string and back to DateTime if it already one in the first place. But then this line is a no-op and the issue is just that you think it's a string but it's actually already a DateTime

Comment: The question was not bad to the begin with, code or not.

Comment: @gurps You should find out if your dataset actually has some parsable data first. Perhaps it is in the wrong format.

Comment: I added to the watch and its coming through as a string value

Comment: Surely by assigning the value back to `dr["Datestamp"]` it's becoming a string again because that's the type of the column. No?

Answer (score -1):

```
const string FMT = "O";

dr["Datestamp"] = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["Datestamp"].ToString(), FMT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip